# Call python script with args from another python script?

Tags: python

Newbie to python. I'm trying to call a python scripts with args from another python script.

Python script `script_with_args.py`  (with args):

```
python script_with_args.py a1 b1 c1 d1

print('Number of arguments:', len (sys.argv), 'arguments.')

print('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

Python script - 2: (call python script - `script_with_args.py`)

```
python script2.py

#call`script_with_args.py`
```

I'm trying to call the `script_with_args.py` from script 2 - `script_with_args.py ab bc ca`

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Have you thought about importing the python script with args to the original and then calling a function from the args script?

Comment: @Alex Does it matter whelther it's homework or not, i have checked few questions where `exec` and `execfile` command is used and `os` to spawn a subprocess . But there was no answer explaining how to pass args in a file. Most of them were import the whole python file with all func inside then calling those.

Comment: Thanks @JohnS. I need to call a python file with args.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you import your args script into your original script using

```
import script_with_args
```

Then you can call a function in script_with_args

Lets use this example...
If both the following script are located in the same folder

1. math_script.py
2. main_script.py

Math script will contain a few function like addition and subtraction we want to call from our main script.

So our main_script will look like...

```
## This is main_script.py
import math_script                        #This will import our script so we can call its functions

numberOne = 2
numberTwo = 3
numberThree = 5
result1 = math_script.add_two(numberOne, numberTwo)
print('The result is:', result1)
result2 = math_script.add_three(numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree)
print('The result is:', result2)
```

And our math_script.py will look like...

```
## This is math_script.py
def add_two(arg1, arg2):
    result = arg1 + arg2
    print('Adding two numbers...')
    return result

def add_three(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3
```

This way you can return the results of your calls with ease and change the arguments you are giving the script in the function calls.

Also to make this work you need to make sure your scripts are in the same folder. If they are not, there are alternative ways you can import them.